# Redux reducer prompting TypeError undefined after UI change

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm currently building out a Redux application sort of like Reddit. To learn about state management.

I have now come across an issue I can't get my head around, when I vote on a post I can see the UI changing(+1/-1 vote) but just a second late in prompt with an error.

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

My component is structured as following

#### API file

```
export const submitPostVote = (option, id) => {
    return axios.post(`${API_URL}/posts/${id}`, {option}, { headers })
}
```

#### Action Creator (using redux-thunk)

```
export function postPostVote(option, id) {
    const request = API.submitPostVote(option, id)

    return (dispatch) => {
        request.then(({data}) => {
            dispatch({type: SUBMIT_POST_VOTE, payload: data})
        });
    };
}
```

#### Reducer

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  const {payload} = action
  switch (action.type){
        case SUBMIT_POST_VOTE:
            return {...state, [payload.data.id]: payload.data}
```

#### Component that uses it

```
import { postPostVote } from '../actions';

<span
 className='fa fa-angle-up voteArrow'
 onClick={() => this.props.postPostVote('upVote', id)}
></span>

export default connect(null, {postPostVote})(PostComponent);
```

---

So I'm trying to pass along  the `option`(upVote || downVote) as well as an id but I cant understand why it returns the error after a can see the change

Much Appreciated,
Petter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got a mismatch between how you're defining fields in the action, and using the action in the reducer.

You're defining your action as `{type: SUBMIT_POST_VOTE, payload: data}`, but in the reducer, using `action.payload.data.id`.  I assume that `payload.data` won't actually exist, and what you really need is `action.payload.id`.

Comment: That's excellent, I did really not think about that what I was actually doing in my action creator was assigning. Thought more about it as a key-value pair. 
Pretty new to this, hah. Thanks